# Geodesic curve induced by the posisitive symmetric matrix

Tags: riemannian-geometry, geodesic

A Riemannian metric $g$ on $M$, n dimensional manifold, is a smooth family of inner products on the tangent spaces of $M$. Namely, $g$ associates to each $p\in M$ a positive definite symmetric bilinear form on $T_p M$, $$g_p:T_p M\times T_p M\to\mathbb R$$ and the smoothness condition on g refers to the fact that the function $$p\in M \to g_p(X_p,Y_p)\in\mathbb R$$ must be smooth for every locally defined smooth vector fields $X, Y$ in $M$.

when I was studying the subject, I wondered what happens if my metric, is of the form $g_p(\xi,\eta)=\xi \cdot A\cdot \eta$, where $A$ is a positive symmetric matrix. How can find the geodesic from this metric? And what happens with a matrix $A=A(x)$?

Comment: The fact is that, on a manifold, there is no canonical way to define "a positive symmetric matrix" as it would require to choose bases of all tangent spaces. That may not be possible to do this globally and smoothly (even continuously is often impossible).

Comment: In addition, finding the geodesics of a given Riemannian manifold can be a very difficult problem.